# What's the proper way of changing the color of SetDlgItemText?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Question is pretty straight forward, I'm using SetDlgItemText to display text, but I want to change the text color from black to grey so it appears grey on the screen. I tried settextcolor, knowing that was a long shot and it didn't work.

EDIT: Here is the code I have that creates the box

```
SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT2, password_string);
```

Comment: And SetDialogItemText is part of... what? Could you at least write the name of the library or framework you're using?

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino it's part of winAPI

Comment: @WakkaDroid - no,it isn't. Perhaps you actually mean `SetDlgItemText`?

Comment: `SetDialogItemText` changes the .. text. It changes the string. It doesn't change the color. To change the text color of a control requires different approaches for different types of control. Sometimes it's not possible at all. It's impossible to help further without you telling us what type of control you're talking about.

Comment: *What's the proper way of changing the color of SetDlgItemText?* `SetDlgItemText` is a function and functions don't have color. It pays to be more studied and precise in use of language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention whether the control is a static or an edit control.
Use code like the following in your dialog proc;
For Edit controls: under `case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:` and for Static controls under `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:`

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    if (::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND) lParam) == IDC_MY_CONTROL)
    {   HBRUSH hbr = (HBRUSH) DefWindowProc(hDlg, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
        SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(192, 192, 192));
        return (BOOL) hbr;
    }
    return FALSE;
```

Comment: Sorry it's edit, so what I have is this line
    SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT2, password_string);
and I want the text to be gray before, and after this one line

Comment: edited the code in my answer for edit controls -- you need to place this code in your dialog proc function

Comment: says that I needed an expression before ::GetDlgCtrlID

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your comment `says that I needed an expression before ::GetDlgCtrlID` -- could you please elaborate?

Comment: It was because I was working in C, so i edited it to work with C, Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Cannot do that with Stock dialogs.

Option #1 - use WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC

- http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/setdlgitemurl.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/GLUZu-zH0TQ

Option #2 - USE RTF by swapping/switching to a Rich Edit Control

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787877(v=VS.85).aspx
- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/49319/