# How to change color of text SetDlgItemText using SetTextColor in win32?

Tags: winapi, win32com, win32-process

As I am working in `Win32`, I want to display a message using `SetDlgItemText`. The message should vary its color depending on success or failure (say for example green for success, red for failure).

The code for the function:
    `if
    {
         //if user does not enter a key
         SetDlgItemText(hDlg, ID_RESULT, L"Please enter a key");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, ID_RESULT, L"Please enter all the user information");
        return false;
    }`

In the above code "Please enter a key" and "Please enter all the user information" should be in red color indicating failure. We set default as green for `ID_RESULT`. Is it possible to change color using `SetTextColor` function in the IF condition itself or else give some other options

Comment: What is the missing ```if``` or ```else if``` condition?

Comment: @Melon - It's if condition,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Edit Control, please refer [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit)

> An edit control that is not read-only or disabled sends the
>   WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to its parent window when the control is about
>   to be drawn. By responding to this message, the parent window can use
>   the specified device context handle to set the text and background
>   colors of the edit control.

If you use Static Control, please refer [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic)

> A static control, or an edit control that is read-only or disabled,
>   sends the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to its parent window when the
>   control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the
>   parent window can use the specified device context handle to set the
>   text foreground and background colors of the static control.

For detailed code operation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890428/11128312).

Comment: What is iMessage in DefWindowProc(hDlg, iMessage, wParam, lParam) ?

Comment: @MohanasudharsanK It represents window messages, iMessage  is just a parameter name. See [DefWindowProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defwindowproca)

Comment: @See [Designing a Window Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-window-procedures#designing-a-window-procedure), you can modify the name of the parameter(such as: iMessage or uMsg...)

Comment: Sun - It works fine using WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC. Thank you.